# Heroku for private server deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, heroku, passenger

anyone knows how to achieve a way to deploy rails apps like heroku on private server?

i use passenger for rails deployment powered by nginx. atm i you capistrano, but i want to just use

```
git push server production
```

for deploying my apps, including migrations.

any suggestions?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used it myself but I think [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) might be just what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

There's some work to be done to enable something like this, but I suspect you could use git's built-in hooks to make something happen:

http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.5.2.5/hooks.html

post-receive and update are probably the two most worth looking into for you.  What you'd want to do is set up a deploy script that runs from there to handle your deployment scenario, whatever that may be.  You won't have all of the other goodness that heroku provides, but you should be able to get a basic deployment working that way.

Answer (score 0):

[Convox](https://convox.com) is an open-source PaaS that you can run in your own AWS account.